# Vue only export "methods" to Jest when I ran unit test, how to export "data" and others?

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, jestjs

I have a very small Vue project, looks like this:

the to be test file:  `src/views/Sum.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    Sum of ({{a}},{{b}}) is: {{sum()}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  data: function(){
    return {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sum: function(){
      console.info("-- in Sum.vue, this: ", this)
      return this.a + this.b
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and the jest test file looks like:

```
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils"
import Sum from '@/views/Sum.vue'

describe('Sum.vue', () => {
  it('should run sum', () => {
    console.info("-- in sum.spec.js, Sum is: " )
    console.info(Sum)
    expect(Sum.methods.sum()).toBe(3)
  })  
})
```

when I ran the test by `$ npm run test:unit`, I got errors:

```
      -- in sum.spec.js, Sum is: 
      { data: [Function: data],
        methods: { sum: [Function: sum] },
        render: [Function: render],
        staticRenderFns: [] }
      -- in Sum.vue, this:  { sum: [Function: sum] }

  ● Sum.vue › should run sum

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 3
    Received: NaN

       6 |     console.info("-- in sum.spec.js, Sum is: " )
       7 |     console.info(Sum)
    >  8 |     expect(Sum.methods.sum()).toBe(3)
         |                               ^
       9 |   })
      10 | })
      11 | 

      at Object.it (tests/unit/say_one.spec.js:8:31)
```

It looks like the `this` acts different in this two context:

- in the spec ( `this = Sum.methods`)
- in the implementation code  ( `this = [Sum.data, Sum.methods, Sum.render]`)

so my question is:

How to make unit tests to the methods that referenced the `data` variables?  (just like the above code  )

thanks so much!

Comment: You are importing shallowMount, but don’t seem to be using it. Usually you would mount/render an instance of a Vue component using a method like shallowMount and manipulate that instance accordingly.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your import, the issue is that you aren’t mounting your component in the test. See the documentation examples of how shallowMount is used https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/shallowMount.html

Comment: you give me a clue,  thanks , I am reading.

Comment: OK, I got it. I should use `wrapper.vm` instead of `Sum`.  what about you post an simple answer? so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it.

thanks to @Alexander Staroselsky, I should use `wrapper.vm` instead of `Sum' in my code.

the correct unit test file should be:

```
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils"
import Sum from '@/views/Sum.vue'

describe('Sum.vue', () => {
  it('should run sum', () => {

    // expect(Sum.methods.sum()).toBe(3)     <--  here I used Sum.methods.sum()

    // below is correct. 
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Sum)
    expect(wrapper.vm.sum()).toBe(3)     
  })  
})
```

the `wrapper.vm` is interesting object, you can visit the variable and methods directly, like :

```
wrapper.vm.a  # => vue.data.a
wrapper.vm.b  # => vue.data.b
wrapper.vm.sum # =>  vue.methods.sum
```

so the code `shallowMount()` is so important whatever you want to test the HTML output or not, you should write this line of code.